# How do you sync ipset sets across two machines?

Tags: linux, iptables, linux-networking, replication

I would like to replicate IPSet sets from one machine (server01) to another machine (server02) using rsync or btsync or something similar. Is that possible? If so how do I do it?

This is a redundancy measure in case server01 is unavailable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ipset save` and `ipset restore` to copy the current state of your IP sets.

For example (run as root on server01):

```
`ipset save | ssh server02 "ipset restore"`
```

There's nothing like rsync for this, unfortunately. But for active/passive failover, the example above should work.

Comment: Thanks. So use crontab to perform ipset save and ipset restore would do the trick I suppose?

Comment: Yes, you could put that in a crontab.

Answer (score 0):

If you could write it to a file on server01 with `ipset save`, `lsyncd` would let you update a file on server02 whenever server01's file changed (it's like doing an rsync whenever anything in the designated directory is changed or updated), and `inotify` could run a script with `ipset restore` to update server02's ipset when that file is changed by `lsyncd`, getting you most of the way there.

The one piece still missing would be something to save it whenever your ipsets on server01 are changed, if you're looking for that functionality. Well,  that, and an answer about 5 years earlier.